# Creating an Android Application that Reads the IMEI of a phone and then compares it to a database

Tags: android, cordova, development-environment, imei

I was asked by my boss to come up with an android application that checks the IMEI of a phone and then compares that IMEI to a database, displaying on the app if the IMEI is registered or not.

I was assigned this project since nobody in the office has the faintest clue on how to do this, and they are not willing to hire outside help (cheapskates).

I am the more tech oriented person in the team, nevertheless I have very little programming experience, basically some very rudimentary Java and I don't have a clue on where to start.

I am hard worker that is willing to put on the hours and learn what is needed, but I could use somebody in pointing me to the tools I need to use and what learning resources I have available online so I can accomplish this task.

I have been looking at PhoneGap and Appbuilder as solutions, but I don't think that those frameworks could give me access to the IMEI on a phone.

I truly appreciate any input that you might have, thank you very much in advance for all your comments.

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and then here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=it

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29)

To get `IMEI` in android you can use the below code..

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imeistr=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

`imeistr` will hold the `IMEI` number of the device..

And you should add the following permission into your Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Try it..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , if you are not so confident about Java you can look at this proper tutorial by Oracle : [Java Official Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/tutorialLearningPaths.html).

Then you can start learning Android from : [Official Android Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html). In case you need any documentation reference look at : [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

You can also try free online Android course on Coursera : [Coursera : Programming mobile applications](https://class.coursera.org/android-001/lecture/preview)

You can learn the database SQLite here: [TutorialsPoint sqlite tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/)
And sqlite in depth with documentation here : [sqlite org](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)
Finally the code which gives you the IMEI number of your phone:

```
public static String getUniqueDeviceId(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    if (deviceId == null) {
        deviceId = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
    return deviceId;
}
```

You need to give following permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```